# When two monitors are attached how to change default from extend displays to duplicate displays?

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors

I have a laptop that uses windows 8 and is connected to a projector.  Every time I connect the two it is default set on extend displays and I want it to default to duplicate displays.  Not only that but sometimes after I have switched to duplicate it will switch back to extend displays on its own.

How can I set it up where it will default to duplicate displays?

Answer (score 0):

Press **Windows Key** + **R** to open the run dialog then type in gpedit.msc and try looking for a setting on there.

Comment: I'm sorry this doesn't answer my question, I specifically asked how to make it default to duplicate.  I am aware of how to change it.  I just am tired of changing it every time I connect the two.

Comment: This makes it default on my PC

Comment: Weird cause that is what I use every time but it never defaults.

Comment: I updated it With hopefully the correct information.

Comment: This is a rather broad uhh... actually vague answer, huh? Go to gpedit.msc and look in there, it's somewhere in there with one of those settings.... LOL!!

Comment: @J.Wilde You need to add the name and path of the setting that is relevant in the Local Group Policy Editor...